# Toggling accordion panel icons with ng-class and ng-click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, angularjs-ng-click

I have an accordion with "chevron" icons that are toggled to point up or down when clicked, this is done with `ng-click` and `ng-class`. The accordion only permits one panel to be open at the same time - so when I click on a panel that is closed, the panel that is open closes. But how do I toggle the chevron icon on the open panel that is getting closed with `ng-click`?

Originally i could do it with DOM manipulation etc, but since this is a partial view in angular I  cannot do it.

Code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" ng-click="firstpaneisopen=!firstpaneisopen">
           <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': firstpaneisopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !firstpaneisopen}"></i> Collapsible Group Item #1
         </a>
      </h4>
     </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
     <div class="panel-body">
       Body
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" ng-click="secondpaneisopen=!secondpaneisopen>
         <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': secondpaneisopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !secondpaneisopen}"></i> Collapsible Group Item #2
       </a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">
       Body
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you check out 'UI Bootstrap' from the AngularUI team. It's a collection of "Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS".

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Their website features an example which shows their Accordion directive using `ng-class` to toggle the chevron icons.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Their directive also features a `close-others` attribute which, if true, will ensure only a single panel is open at any one time.

```
<accordion close-others="true">
```

Comment: This led me to [an equivalent](https://github.com/pineconellc/angular-foundation) for us Foundation users as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I've tried and it seems to work

In my controller I have

```
$scope.menuStatus = [   { isOpen : true     },
                        { isOpen : false    }, 
                        { isOpen : false    } ]
```

In my html I have

```
<accordion id='cntLeftMenu' close-others='false'>
    <accordion-group is-open='menuStatus[0].isOpen'>
        <accordion-heading class='menu-title'>
            Cars <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': menuStatus[0].isOpen , 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !menuStatus[0].isOpen }"></i> 
        </accordion-heading>
        <ul class='left-menu'>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
        </ul>

    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group is-open='menuStatus[1].isOpen'>
        <accordion-heading class='menu-title'>
            Customers <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': menuStatus[1].isOpen , 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !menuStatus[1].isOpen }"></i> 
        </accordion-heading>
        <ul class='left-menu'>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
        </ul>

    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group is-open='menuStatus[2].isOpen'>
        <accordion-heading class='menu-title'>
            Staff <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': menuStatus[2].isOpen , 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !menuStatus[2].isOpen }"></i> 
        </accordion-heading>
        <ul class='left-menu'>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>test1</a></li>
        </ul>

    </accordion-group>


<accordion>
```

Answer (score 4):

**How about working with CSS?**  Bootstrap adds a class `collapsed` on the `html` element that has the `data-toggle="collapse"`.  When the slide opens, it removes this `collapsed` class.  We can then work with `css` to, for example, rotate the `span` element (a child of the element that has the `data-toggle` attribute).

```
<style>

 button.collapsed span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
 }
</style>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
 Simple collapsible
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
 Lorem ipsum dolor...
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : Ensure **`collapsed`** class is added to the element that has the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute for this to work smoothly.  Otherwise, on initial loading of the element, the `span` element doesn't rotate as expected the first time.

Comment: Its good trick  without creating new variables. But only problem I face is, it delays rendering so [] shows before it displays glyphicon.

Comment: @Aamol, you have to ensure the `bootstrap.css` is loaded in the `<head>  tag` and the `<script> tags` should be placed just before the `closing body tag - </body>`.  This will ensure `glyphicons` are available when the page is loaded.  May be also explore `ng-cloak` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18133519/4742733...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution I have ever think. And not to use any controller,

```
<div 
  class="fa fa-fw list-arrow" 
  ng-class="{'fa-angle-down': isClicked, 'fa-angle-right' : !isClicked}" 
  ng-click="isClicked = !isClicked">
</div>
```

You can write similar like me.

Answer (score 2):

Did some researching, I was able to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181594/3195718) to add the class `open` to the `panel-header` when it's toggled open. This is example allows multiple panels to be open and uses [Angular Strap Collapse](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/collapses).

Template:

```
<div class="panel-group" 
     role="tablist" 
     data-ng-model="multiplePanels.activePanels" 
     data-allow-multiple="true" 
     data-bs-collapse>
   <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="location in locations">
       <div class="panel-heading" 
            role="tab" 
            data-ng-class="{'open' : multiplePanels.activePanels.indexOf($index) > -1}"
            bs-collapse-toggle>
            <h3>Some Header Stuff</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="panel-collapse" role="tabpanel" bs-collapse-target>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Stuff in the panel body...</p>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS in the controller:

```
$scope.multiplePanels.activePanels = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap (tested in 4+) collapse and the following styles to toggle the button;

```
<style>
    [id^='particon'] {
      display: block !important;
    }

    [id^='particon']:after {
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      color: grey;
    }

    [id^='particon'].collapse:after {
      content: "\e081";
    }

    [id^='particon'].collapse.show:after {
      content: "\e082";
    }

    /*optional*/
    [id^='particon'].collapsing {
      transition: none;
    }
</style>
```

For fully working snipplet;

https://js.do/code/changecollapseicon

Answer (score 0):

After some research i've got one way to solve this.

JS:

```
$scope.firstpaneisopen = false;
$scope.secondpaneisopen = false;
```

Modified ng-click on the first pane:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" ng-click="firstpaneisopen=!firstpaneisopen; secondpaneisopen=false">
```

vice versa on the second pane.

I don't think this is any elegant solution, especially if we got more than two panes, but it works.