# Angular JS Refresh Pager Directive

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, controller, pager

I have pager directive which depends on data which is received async in controller. Since pager needs to know total count to correctly render pages, I would like to hide whole pager until async data is downloaded, and then show it (but before showing, run link function to setup pager information) along with the data.

How is this possible?

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('App.widgets')
    .directive('customPager', customPager);

function customPager() {
    var pager = {
        scope: {
            pageIndex: '=',
            pageSize: '=',
            recordCount: '=',
            pageClick: '&onPageClick'
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'custom-pager.html',
        link: link
    }

    return pager;

    function link(scope) {
        ....
    }
}})();
```

Comment: are you using a service to fetch your data?

Comment: correct, get data from controller calling a service

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <title>My ParseApp site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <refresh></refresh>

    <script>
        angular.module("testApp", [])
            .directive("refresh", function () {
                return {
                    restrict: "E",
                    template: "<button ng-click=\"refreshPage()\">Refresh this page</button>",
                    link: function (scope, elem) {
                        scope.refreshPage = function () {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                };
            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe this help you [Angularjs - Hide content until DOM loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133319/angularjs-hide-content-until-dom-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

First, In template `'custom-pager.html'`, set an [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) attribute to hide the content of the template.

Second, you'll need to flip the show or hide variable. You can make it visible in several different ways. If the you're caching the $http request in your service, you can simply call it again in your directive and wait for the promise to fire.

Alternatively, your service or controller could broadcast an event when completing the request (check out [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit))